# In place upgrade of SP2007 to SP2010 MOSS

Tags: upgrade

Ran an upgrade of SP2007 to SP2010. All runs through well but then the error log reports:

```
[OWSTIMER] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [4/26/2010 8:16:52 AM]: Upgrade [SharedResourceProvider12 Name=SharedServices1] failed.
[OWSTIMER] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [4/26/2010 8:16:52 AM]: Inner Exception: There are no online service instances for this application.
[OWSTIMER] [SPUpgradeSession] [ERROR] [4/26/2010 8:16:52 AM]:    at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceClient.ExecuteOnChannel(String operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)
```

Can't get into central admin or browse the sites. The timer job can't seem to complete because of the above.

Has anyone else seen similar?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is related, but remember that after doing an in-place upgrade you must manually configure your timer jobs.

[Shameless plug for my whitepaper on upgrade](http://andersrask.spoint.me/2010/03/22/whitepaper-on-sharepoint-upgrade/)

Comment: mmm any pointers on that? Dont see anything specific on technet

Comment: oh i think it was mentioned on one of Sean Livingstones upgrade sessions on SharePoint Conf. in Las Vegas, but would have to recheck

Comment: I gotta go to Vegas! lol